# create a list of selects form a json.

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a question i tray to create a group of selects form a json using jquery. I do not quite understand how I can achieve and get the label options for a loop with json

```
{
  "listOfOptions" :  [
    {
      "Option1" :  [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Pine"
         },
        {
          "id": "a02",
          "name": "Birch"
        }
      ],

      "Option2" :  [
        {
          "id": "a01",
          "name": "Pine"
        },
        {
          "id": "a02",
          "name": "Birch"
        }
      ],

      "Option3" :  [
        {
          "id": "a01",
          "name": "Pine"
        },
        {
          "id": "a02",
          "name": "Birch"
        }
      ]    
    }    
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to create a loop that lets me get the label and options of Selects from this json

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data/data.json',
  dataType:'JSON',
  success: function(listOfOptions {
      $.each(listOfOptions, function(key, item) {
            $.each(item, function(i, val) {
                alert(val);
            })
        }
        }
});
```

Comment: You would just access then like `val.id` and `val.name` then do whatever you need to do with them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$.each(listOfOptions.listOfOptions[0],function(k,v) {
    var optHTML = $('<label/>', {text:k + ': '}).append( $('<select/>') ).append( '<br/>' );
    $.each(v, function(key,value) {
        optHTML.find('select').append( $('<option/>',{value:value.id,text:value.name}) );
    });
    $('body').append( optHTML );
});
```

```js
var listOfOptions = {
  "listOfOptions" :  [
    {
      "Option1" :  [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Pine"
         },
        {
          "id": "a02",
          "name": "Birch"
        }
      ],

      "Option2" :  [
        {
          "id": "a01",
          "name": "Pine"
        },
        {
          "id": "a02",
          "name": "Birch"
        }
      ],

      "Option3" :  [
        {
          "id": "a01",
          "name": "Pine"
        },
        {
          "id": "a02",
          "name": "Birch"
        }
      ]    
    }    
  ]
};
$.each(listOfOptions.listOfOptions[0],function(k,v) {
  var optHTML = $('<label/>', {text:k + ': '}).append( $('<select/>') ).append( '<br/>' );
  $.each(v, function(key,value) {
    optHTML.find('select').append( $('<option/>',{value:value.id,text:value.name}) );
  });
  $('body').append( optHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```